# There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Created a directory

```
1) mkdir -p /root/dists/archives/
```

Downloaded debians required for installing few packages say python-stdeb devscripts in /root/dists/archives/

```
2) cd /root/dists/archives/

3) dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null | gzip -9c > Packages.gz
```

4) Added below entry in /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb file:/root/dists/archives/ ./

5) apt-get update
Ign file: ./ InRelease
Ign file: ./ Release.gpg
Ign file: ./ Release
Ign file: ./ Translation-en_US
Ign file: ./ Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
```

6) When I try to install the following packages python-stdeb devscripts. It is throwing the below error

```
apt-get install -y  python-stdeb devscripts
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
```

Answer (score 1):

**Create a file in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d**

```
# cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02allow-unsigned
APT::Get::AllowUnauthenticated 1;
# apt-get update
```